# On the definition of Banach space

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

In physics, it is not unusual to employ spaces where vectors' lengths can be of either sign. (See, e.g., the Gupta formalism in quantum electrodynamics.) Physicists call such constructions "Hilbert spaces with indefinite metric." This is a mathematical oxymoron, but it is harmless because a simple [development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_inner_product_space) suggested by [Mark G. Krein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Krein) enables an indefinite inner product to generate an auxiliary semi-definite inner product. The latter product, in its turn, generates a positive-definite norm, with respect to which the space becomes Hilbert (provided it is complete).

How about the Banach spaces that are not Hilbert (and are lacking a fixed link between the inner product and norm, or are even lacking an inner product as such)? Is it all right for a Banach space to have a norm of an indefinite sign?

Comment: If you want to talk about a "norm of an indefinite sign", just don't use the term "Banach space", call it by some other name, for example a "$\beta$-space" or whatever other name ones creativity leads them to (off the top of my head, I can't remember any vector spaces with such a structure, though I wouldn't be surprised if people have already thought about it). Make a clear definition, and don't overload standard terminology, and then you can talk about whatever you want.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see that the definition of a Banach space requires the norm to be positive definite. In the theory of Banach spaces, does there exist a remedy analogous to Krein's construction in the theory of Hilbert spaces? -- so that we begin with a complete space of an indefinite norm, and build for it an auxiliary norm, which is  positive definite, and with respect to which the space becomes Banach?